# How to show f is a linear transformation?

Tags: limits, derivatives, homogeneous-equation

Let $f: R^n \to R$ be a continuous function on $R^n$ that is homogeneous of degree 1. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at the origin $(0, 0)$. Prove that $f$ is a linear transformation.

This is what I have so far.
In order to show f is a linear transformation it must satisfy two conditions.

1) $f(t\cdot x) = t\cdot f(x)$, this is satisfied by f as it is homogenous of degree 1.

2) $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, I have been told to prove this by using the fact that

$$(Df)_pu = \lim  (1/t)\cdot(f(p + tu) − f(p)) \quad\text{as}\quad  t\to0$$

Can anyone show me how to arrive at this conclusion from this?

Answer (score 0):

HINT. Differentiate termwise the equation
$$
f(tx)=tf(x), 
$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed.

Comment: (∂jf)(tx) = t^(s−1)*(∂jf)(x) = t^0*(∂jf)(x) = (∂jf)(x), is this what you mean by that?

Comment: I don't understand what you write. But it is much easier than you think. I cannot really give any more hints.